# Is there a way to extract the source code from deb or rpm packages?

Tags: package-management, source-code

I find that this would be very useful in certain situations in which I want to install software in a different way, or change flags, or not let the software manager know the program has been installed (so it wouldn't look for updates). I know packages can be built from source codes, and this is relatively common, but I don't know about the other way around. It would also be useful for converting one type of package into another when [**Alien**](http://kitenet.net/~joey/code/alien/) doesn't work or doesn't provide good results. I've been searching on-line but there seems to be no or few records of source code extraction from pre-built packages...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Debian and RPM packages don't contain source code, only the compiled result.  However, you can fetch the source packages - SRPMS, or the Debian description, patch, and original tarball.

Those can be recompiled with whatever local modifications you want, and will more or less do what you want - though remember to adjust the version number to make it clear that your version is "later" than the distribution version.

Comment: So, there is no way to convert a package I already have into source code?

Comment: Not directly; both apt and yum offer tools to download the source package by name, but you can't extract what isn't present from the binary files.